# How to synchronize OSC and Filter envelope by note gate in AudioKit

Tags: audiokit

In other words I need two separate ADSR envelopes for OSC bank & Filter (cutoff). How I can synchronize this two things by note press?

AMOscillatorBank(amplitude)->lowPassFilter(cutoff)->AudioKit output
When 'amplitude' & 'cutoff' have separated adsr envelopes, and generate & transform sound by chain two output.

I trying some examples in playground, but i only can create AMOscillatorBank(amplitude) with adsr & only pass some lowpassfilter (but not syncronized to note press).

Answer (score 0):

If you want sample accuracy you'll need to put the low pass filter inside the DSP for the bank. We're actually doing that on the AK Synth One project that will be open sourced when it is finished.

Comment: Thank you for response Aurelius! Does this actually mean, this is not can be done with "just connecting nodes"? This is more low level task? To my question - I'am trying to do this with AKOperationEffect, but not successfully: AKOscillatorBank (protocols noteOn & noteOff) working fine, but this don't help me with effect parameters envelope, i'ts working "stand alone".